# Remote test instance for Oracle 11g with JDBC access

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

I would like to use an Oracle database instance to run 11g (or newer) on some remote server (as a playground for private projects). The purpose of this would be to do some testing / developing with a Java backend, so I need JDBC access.

There is LiveSQL and APEX as testing platforms, but neither one of them supports JDBC access. 
So what I'm looking for is sth. like LiveSQL / Apex WITH JDBC access.
Does that exist?

I do have an own root server, so I could install Oracle 11g by myself, but unfortunately my server has only 2GB RAM, which is not enough, so the installation fails.

**Update:** Unfortunately I need Oracle, as most projects have Oracle. 
I also have a local installation of Oracle XE on my 1) Desktop at home, 2) private Laptop and 3) Laptop at work. But then again, these Oracle instances are never in sync and I don't want to sync them all the time. By using one single remote instance, I could avoid all those installations.

Comment: Why don't you just install Oracle XE somewhere in your network.

Comment: Or on a VM on your local machine (even with [a prebuilt VM](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html#dbapp) if you're just playing).

Comment: There is a new Oracle XE (https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html) that was released recently, you can use that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Oracle Database Cloud service https://cloud.oracle.com/database which you can try for free. Once you have started a database instance you can enable remote sqlnet access. This will let you connect remotely using the JDBC thin driver (or sqlplus or any client).

Comment: Thank you. That's, what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need Oracle for any particular reason? If you're just testing/coding, an im memory db commes in very handy. My favorite is [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).

H2 commes with an [Oracle compatibility mode](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility).

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I need Oracle, as most projects have Oracle. I do have MySQL on my Root Server, but I would like to avoid the chore of transforming MySQL to Oracle SQL. I also have a local installation of Oracle XE on my 1) Desktop at home, 2) private Laptop and 3) Laptop at work. But then again, these Oracle instances are never in sync.

Comment: H2 has an Oracle compatibility mode. I use this a lot, to make sure my queries are working on H2 and Oracle.

Comment: Oh, that's great, I didn't know about that H2 compatibility mode. Then it sounds interesting again to install H2 on my Root server. So is it REALLY compatible? Or do I need some re-work nevertheless.